# What is the most numerically precise method for dividing sums or differences?

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, sum, numeric, division

Consider `(a-b)/(c-d)` operation, where `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` are floating-point numbers (namely, `double` type in C++). Both `(a-b)` and `(c-d)` are (`sum`-`correction`) pairs, as in [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). Briefly, the specific of these (`sum`-`correction`) pairs is that `sum` contains a large value relatively to what's in `correction`. More precisely, `correction` contains what didn't fit in `sum` during summation due to numerical limitations (53 bits of mantissa in `double` type).

What is the numerically most precise way to calculate `(a-b)/(c-d)` given the above speciality of the numbers?

Bonus question: it would be better to get the result also as (`sum`-`correction`), as in Kahan summation algorithm. So to find `(e-f)=(a-b)/(c-d)`, rather than just `e=(a-b)/(c-d)` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `div2` algorithm of [Dekker (1971)](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN001170007&physid=PHYS_0232) is a good approach.

It requires a `mul12(p,q)` algorithm which can exactly computes a pair `u+v = p*q`. Dekker uses a method known as Veltkamp splitting, but if you have access to an `fma` function, then a much simpler method is

```
u = p*q
v = fma(p,q,-u)
```

the actual division then looks like (I've had to change some of the signs since Dekker uses additive pairs instead of subtractive):

```
r   = a/c
u,v = mul12(r,c)
s   = (a - u - v - b + r*d)/c
```

The the sum `r+s` is an accurate approximation to `(a-b)/(c-d)`.

UPDATE: The subtraction and addition are assumed to be left-associative, i.e.

```
s = ((((a-u)-v)-b)+r*d)/c
```

This works because if we let `rr` be the error in the computation of `r` (i.e. `r + rr = a/c` exactly), then since `u+v = r*c` exactly, we have that `rr*c = a-u-v` exactly, so therefore `(a-u-v-b)/c` gives a fairly good approximation to the correction term of `(a-b)/c`.

The final `r*d` arises due to the following:

```
(a-b)/(c-d) = (a-b)/c * c/(c-d) = (a-b)/c *(1 + d/(c-d)) 
            = [a-b + (a-b)/(c-d) * d]/c
```

Now `r` is also a fairly good initial approximation to `(a-b)/(c-d)` so we substitute that inside the `[...]`, so we find that `(a-u-v-b+r*d)/c` is a good approximation to the correction term of `(a-b)/(c-d)`

Comment: By `return r+s` do you mean `e=r` and `f=-s` in the expression `(e-f)=(a-b)/(c-d)` ? Or is there a mistake and indeed `e=r` and `f=s` (without negating `s`)?

Comment: The result should be `r+s  = (a-b)/(c-d)`

Comment: I haven't checked the approach yet (need substantial time to think in depth), but the `fma()` thing is extremely useful, +1. Basically, doesn't `(a - u - v - b + r*d)` lose precision, or is Kahan summation expected here?

Comment: So I've thought in depth and now I understand everything except the addition of `r*d` : how does it make the result more numerically precise?

Comment: I've added an explanation for the origin of `r*d`

Answer (score 0):

For tiny corrections, maybe think of

```
(a - b) / (c - d) = a/b (1 - b/a) / (1 - c/d) ~ a/b (1 - b/a + c/d)
```